# JavaFX Application not loading fxml files when exported to a jar file

Tags: javafx, jar, fxml

I have just finished my first java project, however I can't seem to get it to build properly. It will load the initial fxml file that the whole calculator runs on, however when I try to add a holiday/break in the holiday/break menu a dialogpane is supposed to display so the user can fill information, but I keep getting a location not set error when I run the jar file in the cmd. It all works when I launch it in intellij but not in the jar.

This is how I have my files set up. I made a resource directory in the FinishedCalCulator project and marked it as the resource root

[image: File Structure]

This is how I set the Location of the FXML file into the loader. This works when I run it in Intellij but not in the jar file.

[image: Method call]

Project Structure
[image: Project Structure]

Running through CMD
[image: Running through CMD]

Invocation Target Exception/Location not set error
[image: Invocation Target Exception/Location not set error]

I have looked around and found a few posts talking about putting all of the fxml files into a resource file and I did that and got it working again in Intellij, but it still will not display the dialog panes when I try to add them. I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here. I don't think I fully understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your resource file is named `AddHolidayDialog.fxml` yet you are searching for it with `getClass().getResource("/addHolidayDialog.fxml")`. Notice the difference of case in the "A"? The "file system" of a JAR file is _case sensitive_. However, Windows' file system is not. Thus, it works when ran from Intellij but not from the JAR.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. Post code as text formatted as code blocks instead. In this case the only additional info the screenshot provides is the name of the `getResource` method parameter and highlighting the occurances of `dialog`. This info is unimportant to the question though. The stack trace should be posted as text (code block) too instead of a screenshot; it should be simple enough to redirect the error stream to a text file and copy&paste it to the question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Answer (score 5):

*To expand on my comment...*

## Answer

In your code you are calling `getResource("/addHolidayDialog.fxml")`. Your resource's filename, however, is `AddHolidayDialog.fxml`. Simply change the "a" in your code to "A" and your code should work.

---

## Explanation

#### Running from Intellij

When you run your application from Intellij it uses the output files in the `out/production/classes` directory. In other words, the classes are not in a JAR file. When you call `getClass().getResource("/addHolidayDialog.fxml")` you will get a `URL` like:

`file://C:/.../out/production/classes/addHolidayDialog.fxml`

Which works on Windows despite the fact the file is *actually* named `AddHolidayDialog.fxml` because Windows has a *case-insensitive* file system.

#### Running from JAR

Then you export your project to a JAR and run it from there. Calling the same `getResource` code you will now get a `URL` (if the code worked) like:

`jar:file://C:/.../your-application.jar!/addHolidayDialog.fxml`

What your code actually returns from `getResource`, however, is `null`. According to the JAR file, the resource `addHoldiayDialog.fxml` doesn't exist. It'll happily tell you that `AddHolidayDialog.fxml` *does* exist, however. The reason for this being that a JAR file has a *case-sensitive* "file system".

Comment: Thank you it was that simple. I should have caught that, I didn't know windows would actually run it if the file name was wrong. Thanks for the information.